# Need help get URI Segment using Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, segment

How segment works in Yii Framework?

Example....

```
http://myblog.com/index.php/controller/method/id/5
```

How to get 5?

Without params are possible in Yii like Codeigniter `$product_id = $this->uri->segment(4);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by

```
$_GET['id'];
```

It goes like this....

```
controller/method/param1/value1/param2/value2.... so far so forth
```

Comment: Without id is possible like codeigniter $product_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

Comment: Haven't worked in a while in Yii so I am not so sure on the segmented structure. But you can get a variable value form URL by above procedure that I am sure of.

Comment: yah its work with **parmas and $_GET['id']** but i want without parmas like codeigniter

Comment: diffrent frameworks have different implementation. If you want you can tweak the framework to do so but it'l be like solving a problem that never existed.

Comment: I need to know how to get parameters values in yii2 as per above question.

Answer (score 1):

@itachi's answer is correct.

You can use : `$_GET['id']`

Yii uses a different type of url management, using the CUrlManager class. The [parsePathInfo()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#parsePathInfo-detail) function of this class :

> Parses a path info into URL segments and **saves** them to **$_GET** and **$_REQUEST**.